# 'The Secret People' a poem by G.K. Chesteron: Is "Blood runs red" a proverb or is it literary language?

Tags: expressions, poetry

The line I am referring to is as follows:

> The fine French kings came over in a flutter of flags and dames.
>   We liked their smiles and battles, but we never could say their names.
>   **The blood ran red** to Bosworth and the high French lords went down;
>   There was naught but a naked people under a naked crown.

Is '*The blood ran red*' a saying which the poem comprehend or is it literary language of which I have to make sense for myself.

Comment: It's probably archaic, certainly in a literary register. Though transparent in meaning, it may be indeterminate as to whether 'red' is a depictive adjective or a flat adverb.

Comment: [Bosworth Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Bosworth_Field) was the last battle of the Wars of the Roses, and the end of the Plantagenet ("French") kings of England.  It was also quite a bloody battle; when Chesterton says "the blood ran red" he simply means that a lot of blood was spilled on the battlefield.

Comment: so no official answers ... question done.

Comment: Had it been English aristocracy, then the blood would have run blue.